# ASUS TUF FX505TF on Linux?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, asus

I just bought a new laptop, it's ASUS TUF FX505DT, here's the specs:

- AMD® Ryzen™ 5 3550H Processor
- DDR4 2400MHz SDRAM
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 , with 4GB GDDR5 VRAM
- 256GB PCIe® Gen3 SSD

I was wondering if this would work well if I'd switch my OS to Linux, Ubuntu to be specific. I'm running Ubuntu on my old laptop (it's HP Pavilion), and Linux is working well on it.

I figured out to ask others who have the same laptop as mine if Linux does work well in this laptop before I switch Windows to Linux. I also heard that NVIDIA doesn't work well with Linux.

Comment: Hmm there is a reason why we have a live usb session. You can check out Linux yourself with one without altering ANYTHING on your current system, It is also 1 of the reason why we do not accept these kind of questions. The other: Linux requires a different skill set and mind set than windows. If you lack either Linux might feel like a roadblock. If you do have affinity with it it will be a breeze to use. I myself love tinkering with my systems and hate it when the OS is hindering me if I want to do something. Command line is my friend so to say :D

Comment: And nvidia never is a problem using Linux. They love us. What does happen is that the bleeding edge graphics card might take a few months to get added to the drivers.